# Proof and explanation of the base 2 integer sqare root algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, proof, sqrt

While looking for a reasonably fast algorithm to calculate a square root of a number up to n digits I have stumbled upon this algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_(base_2)

I must admit, this is a beautiful piece of code, but the explanation provided on wikipedia doesn't really speak to me. I have tried to understand it for several hours now and I simply have no idea how does it work - I have done some example calculations on paper but It didn't seem to help.

So, that's why I ask this question here, an explanation would be something really useful.

Also, if this method is supposed to be much quicker, why It is not the one used in standard C library?

Comment: Looks profoundly complicated for what it's trying to achieve, and probably it's not used in the standard C library because it is in fact not that much faster. Numerous typos make me nervous about the author's credentials and the amount of scrutiny to which this contribution has been subjected.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say: "the one used in standard C library"?. The C standard doesn't specify algorithms. A given *implementation* of C will have to implement `sqrt`. Are you looking at a particular implementation? If so, which one? Can you give a pointer to the code? On a typical desktop/laptop machine (for example based on an Intel Core CPU), `sqrt` will be implemented in hardware, so all the C implementation has to do is know how to compile to the appropriate hardware instruction, leaving the actual algorithm to the hardware.